# Evaluating convoluted integrals of complex exponentional and rational

Tags: calculus, integration, convolution

I want to evaluate the following integral: 
\begin{equation} 
f_{abcd}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\lambda\int_0^{t-\lambda} d\tau \frac{e^{i a \tau}}{ (b+i \tau)^{5/2} }  
\int_0^{t-\lambda} d\tau \left( \frac{e^{i c \tau}}{ (d+i \tau)^{5/2} } \right)^*,
\end{equation}
where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are real positive constants; $t$ is a real positive variable.

We can rewrite this as: 
\begin{equation} 
f_{abcd}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\lambda \:g_{ab}(t-\lambda) \:\left(g_{cd}(t-\lambda)\right)^*.
\end{equation}
where we have defined
\begin{equation} 
g_{ab}(t) =     \int_{0}^t  d\tau \, 
\frac{e^{i a \tau}}{ (b+i \tau)^{5/2} } 
\end{equation}

Now the integral $g_{ab}(t)$ can be evaluated and expressed as function of the complex error function erfi.

The problem then is that I don't know how to evaluate the integral $\int d\lambda$ to obtain $f(t)$. I am not even sure it has a definite form.

I tried to play with the boundaries of integration, or write the integral as sum of separate integrals, but without success. Any idea is welcome!

Comment: According to sage, $g_{ab}(t)=-\frac{i\sqrt{-ab-iat}a\sqrt{b+it}b^2e^{-ab}\Gamma\left(-\frac32,-ab-iat\right)}{b^{3}+3ib^2t-3bt^2-it^3}+\frac{2  \sqrt{-a b - i  a t} a \sqrt{b + i  t} b t e^{\left(-a b\right)} \Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}, -a b - i  a t\right)}{b^{3} + 3 i  b^{2} t - 3  b t^{2} - i  t^{3}} + \frac{i  \sqrt{-a b - i  a t} a \sqrt{b + i  t} t^{2} e^{\left(-a b\right)} \Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}, -a b - i  a t\right)}{b^{3} + 3 i  b^{2} t - 3  b t^{2} - i  t^{3}} + \frac{i  \sqrt{-a b} a e^{\left(-a b\right)} \Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}, -a b\right)}{\sqrt{b}}$

Comment: Note that $f_{abcd}(t)$ does not depend on $t$ (change the integration variable $λ$ into $λ-t$). You can try to proceed switching to Fourier transforms or, if $g_{ab}(t)$ vanishes for negative $t$ to complex Laplace transforms. The last gives a promising result if you know the complex Laplace transform of $g_{ab}(t)$.